# Getting error in Unix as awk : can't open

Tags: unix, awk

I want to store as `SOURCEIP=abc0300ux500.apps.bc.abcde.com`. But getting below error.
Can you please tell me why I'm getting below error?

```
abc0300ux500:/home/a4b2spxt >> echo $chc

01 abc0300ux500.apps.bc.abcde.com Oct@2016


abc0300ux500:/home/a4b2spxt >> export SOURCEIP=`echo $chc| awk -F " " '{print $2}'`

awk: can't open {print $2}
```

Comment: What OS are you on? Does it work any better with `awk "{print \$2}"`?  (Also, you don't need the `-F`. The field separator you want is already the default.)

Comment: In Unix I'm trying to run that command.

Answer (score 0):

Removed -F " " part. Run as below. Now it is working.

abc0300ux500:/home/a4b2spxt >> export SOURCEIP=`echo $chc| awk '{print $2}'`